# Change Chrome default completion behavor

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to change the default behavior of Chrome ctrl+enter completion from http:// to https://?

for example in the address bar type 'google' then ctrl+enter should take me to https://www.google.com

Answer (score 0):

The [EFF](https://www.eff.org) has released [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere), a great tool that does exactly what you wand: Use HTTPS instead of HTTP. This should not only work when using ctrl+enter, but also when clicking links to HTTP sites or when the browser follows a redirection. You can get it from the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/https-everywhere/gcbommkclmclpchllfjekcdonpmejbdp) or from the [official website](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere).